# Estimating the Parameters of Multivariate Gaussian from Conditioned Distributions

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, estimation, multivariate-analysis, references

My goal is estimating the distribution parameters of a multivariate Gaussian $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ from observations that were generated from different conditioned variants of this distribution. That is, I have observations $x_1, \ldots, x_N$ where each $x_i$ is generated from $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma)$ conditioned on a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

For example, for $n=2$, we assume each $x_i$ to be drawn from $X_i | <X_i,v_i>=0$ with known nonzero $v_i\in\mathbb{R}^2$. For $v_i=(1,0)$ or $v_i=(0,1)$ the parameters of the Gaussian distribution generating $x_i$ are well known and can be obtained e.g. from [here](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/gaussianprocess/node7.html) (there: theorem 4, Part b. Note: this link is the result of a quick search and uses slightly different notation). However, I am interested in the original parameters  $\mu$ and $\Sigma$. In order to do this, I have more than two observations $x_i$ with at least 3 different values for $v_i$.

I feel that I'm probably not the first person interested in this but I was not successful in finding literature. Thus, I am looking for potential references addressing this problem.

Comment: Perhaps you should more explicitly spell out your scenario, i.e., the conditioning on a linear subspace of $R^n$.

Comment: Tried to clarify by providing an example in 2d.

Comment: Theorem 4 part b is a well-known result, of which I was well aware and have often used. But it's still not clear to me how it applies to your situation. Is each observation in a lower dimensional space than $R^n$, maybe not all even in the same dimension? Are you hoping to get enough "equations" for conditional means (in lower dimension) and conditional covariances in lower dimension that you can back out all the entries in $\mu$ and $\Sigma$, maybe with some kind of fitting procedure? I suppose some kind of optimization problem can be formed, but those parameters may not be indentifiable.

Comment: You may need to formulate this as a semi--definite optimization problem (SDP), i.e., including a constraint that the full covariance matrix be positive semi-definite. That's not necessarily a big deal. But working out the details of what you need in your fitting procedure may get somewhat involved. I think it's going to be a very "nasty" problem at best to numerically solve. Sounds more like  a research project to answer than a Stack Exchange answer.

Comment: And if you're not conditioning exclusively on individual components or collections thereof, then theorem 4 part b doesn't even apply.

Comment: I upvoted your comments as your guessing therein is correct and the problem also seems somewhat "nasty" to me. Indeed, I hope to obtain $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ from conditional means and covariances in lower dimensions. Particularly, your last comment hits an important point. In the 2d case, it can be easily seen that merely conditioning on the components is not enough to reconstruct the full bivariate distribution parameters. This procedure would yield only 4 values (2 means, 2 variances), whereas a bivariate gaussian has 5 (2 mean, 2 var, 1 correlation).

Comment: Can you describe the real-world scenario, if any, in which this estimation problem arises?

Comment: So far, this is mostly out of intellectual curiosity motivated by having this type of distributions being one of the building blocks for defining uncertainty for unit dual quaternions in order to represent uncertain poses, e.g. for robotics or aerospace. However, for the problem I have within that particular scenario I asked [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/211634/multivariate-linear-regression-with-linear-constraints) a similar question addressing a slightly different case.